# capturing UDP streaming data

Tags: sockets, udp, vlc

I write a simple UDP service that listens for incoming UDP packet that sent from vlc player.
problem is that size of data in each extraction is about 2KB; and final output size of a 93 MB file is something about 14 KB. =)

should I call setsocketOpt for increasing recv buffer size?

I want to know is there any problem with my socket thats cuts data? (data loss)
OR
the extracted data need to be decompressed and further processing?

I'm using C++ winSock library.
some output data is as follows:

```
G@GGG@DGG@DGGGGGG@DGGGGG@DGGGGGG@DGGGGGG@DGGGGGGGGGG@GG@DGGGGGG@DG@EG@E
G@EGGGGGGGGGGG@DG@G@DGGGG@EG@EG@EG@B9GGGGG@DGGGGG@DGGGGG@GGGGGGG@DG@D
GG@DGGGGGGGGGG@DGGG@E2|ØzþG@EGGGGGGGG@DG@DGGGGGGGGGGGGGG@DGGGGG@D
G@B2GGG@DG@DG@EG@GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG@GGGGGGGG@EGGGG@DGGGGGGGG@DGGGG@E
GGGGGGGGGGG@DGGGGGGGGG@DGGGGGGGGGGGG@EGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP is a message based protocol and packets have definite boundaries. There cannot be reception of partial packets. That is, you will either get the complete message or you will not get it.

UDP is suited for applications that can tolerate packet loss or un-ordered packet delivery but cannot compromise on delay or jiter.

TCP is for applications that can accept delay but cannot compromise on packet loss or ordering of packets. So, if you want a entire file of 93MB to be reassembled by transferring fragmented packets over the network such that no packets are dropped, then TCP/SCTP is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

UPD is not a streaming protocol. A UDP read returns you one packet. Packets might be lost, reordered and even duplicated. Your code must deal with that fact.

Buffer sizes have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Not quite. A larger buffer size may reduce packet loss.

Comment: I'm not sure what the buffer size setting even means and how the kernel works with it. If you set it to 1 byte I cannot imagine the kernel dropping packets that are > 1 byte. I don't know if UDP receive buffer size can even be influenced.

Comment: Yes. I tried to set socket rcvbuf to 32K and it was set correctly; but still 1316 is the number of bytes recieved. I guess it's an external (kernel or ...) limitation.

Comment: Make no mistake, this is *your* bug. The kernel and network are able to process UDP just fine. Other applications don't seem to have any trouble with that data stream.